# What are the exponent characters (in non-formatted text)? How can I create these exponent characters?

Tags: html, unicode, icons, ascii, plaintext

I´m searching for a list of exponents like ¹²³ and so on and the same with letters. Note these still remain superscripted even in plain text.
Does something like these exist? If not, how can I create those?

(I need them for a website-project)

Comment: Are you looking for [unicode superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)?

Comment: @kabanus Yes something like this. I found some letters i need but now i have one little design problem. For example "◌ͯ" - "exponent x" has this circle under it, can i remove it?

Comment: @kabanus I found a html5 tag named "sup" which allowes me to create some kind of texts. Thank you for your time.

Comment: All 10 digits exist. Not all letters exist as markup. Please use markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode versions of superscripted/subscripted characters exist for all ten digits but not for all letters. They remain superscripted/subscripted in a plain-text environment without the need of format tags such as `<sup>`/`<sub>`.

However (as of v14), **not all letters have Unicode superscripts**. Furthermore, they are scattered along different Unicode ranges, and are in fact used mainly for phonetic transcription. Additionally, they are used for compatibility purposes especially if the text does not support markup superscripts and subscripts.

## Exponent characters:

These are mostly used for mathematical and referencing usage.

```
 - ⁰ [U+2070]
 - ¹ [U+00B9, Latin-1 Supplement]
 - ² [U+00B2, Latin-1 Supplement]
 - ³ [U+00B3, Latin-1 Supplement]
 - ⁴ [U+2074]
 - ⁵ [U+2075]
 - ⁶ [U+2076]
 - ⁷ [U+2077]
 - ⁸ [U+2078]
 - ⁹ [U+2079]
 - ⁺ [U+207A]
 - ⁻ [U+207B]
 - ⁼ [U+207C]
 - ⁽ [U+207D]
 - ⁾ [U+207E]
 - ⁿ [U+207F]
 - ⁱ [U+2071]
```

The "linear", "squared", and "cubed" subscripts are the most familiar and are found in Latin-1 Supplement. All the others are found in Superscripts and Subscripts. Add 0x2070 to all the non-Latin-1 Supplement superscripts to obtain the code point value of these digits. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) and the official [Unicode codepage segment](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf).

## Interesting notes

There are also subtle differences between `<sup>` subscripts and Unicode subscripts; Unicode subscripts are entirely different codepoints altogether, and some fonts professionally design subscripted letters because `<sup>` subscripts may look thin.

Compare **x²** with **x<sup>2</sup>**, similarly **x⁺** with **x<sup>+</sup>** (the first involves Unicode, the second is markup)

The best solution is to use markup, such as `<sup>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create the characters, but you can format then as super-scripts if you are generating HTML.

As to find which exist, you just have to use an unicode-character searching resource and look for "superscript" to have a listing -

This query, for example:
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=superscript&preview=entity

As you can see, all digits are available (more than once, even), but very few letters.

However, if you intend to generate HTML output, the `<sup>` tag will work for any text you want, and give the necessary semantic meaning to the text  - you can read about it and try it online here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup